# Getting user ID in lambda function (go 1.x) from AWS API Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, next.js, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I updated the API (rest) via the amplify CLI to add a path and function (go 1.x), and within the function, I was able to retrieve the user ID via the following:

```
event.RequestContext.Identity.CognitoAuthenticationProvider
```

and this worked just fine.

I repeated the same steps above, however, when trying to retrieve the user id (sub) from the same as above, nothing is being retrieved. I'm not sure why, I've checked API gateway, and the settings seem to be the same, but maybe I'm missing something?

Any idea how to get the user id/sub in the function?

further info:

When accessing the "invoke URL" for the former function, an error message shows:

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

However, this is not the case when accessing the invoke URL for the latter function. The latter function is not expecting an authentication token, how can that be changed?

EDIT: as requested, the JSON response for event.RequestContext:

```
{
    "accountId": "000000000000",
    "resourceId": "00aaaa",
    "stage": "dev",
    "domainName": "a00aaaaa00.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com",
    "domainPrefix": "a00aaaaa00",
    "requestId": "000aa0a0-000a-0000-0000-aa0000a00aaa",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
    "identity": {
        "cognitoIdentityPoolId": "",
        "accountId": "",
        "cognitoIdentityId": "",
        "caller": "",
        "apiKey": "",
        "apiKeyId": "",
        "accessKey": "",
        "sourceIp": "00.000.000.000",
        "cognitoAuthenticationType": "",
        "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": "",
        "userArn": "",
        "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36",
        "user": ""
    },
    "resourcePath": "/xxxxpath",
    "path": "/dev/xxxxpath",
    "authorizer": null,
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "requestTime": "14/May/2022:23:09:05 +0000",
    "requestTimeEpoch": 1652569745072,
    "apiId": "a00aaaaa00"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add the full dump of `event.RequestContext` to the question

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary - it is as follows, with values changed:

{789658565444 69ewqc  dev xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com xxxxxxxxxx 000aa0a0-000a-0000-0000-aa0000a00aaa HTTP/1.1 {       *IP ADDRESS*    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36 } /xxxxpath /dev/xxxxpath map[] POST 14/May/2022:22:01:31 +0000 6858888787878 xxxxxxxxxx}

Comment: Is that the entire object? Convert it to JSON please and then add it to the question. More specifically what’s inside `event.RequestContext.Identity` 

Comment: But hm - does whatever function you’re trying to invoke have a route with Cognito enabled on it? If it doesn’t need auth, that field will never be set.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I will get the JSON soon, but I’m the mean time, how do I check if the function has a route with cognitive enabled on it? I’m a bit new to this and want to make sure I’m looking in the right place, thanks!

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary - posted json in the question

Comment: So this happened after upgrading go? Or adding a new endpoint? You say it was working before, what have you exactly done?